# How to restrict user to input data using datetimepicker and disable manual user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I want to restrict the user to only input data using the datetimepicker. Below is the code I am using:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Start</label>
    <div class="input-group date" id="dtp1">
        <input type="text" id="txtStart" class="form-control" readonly="readonly"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#dtp1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A',
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
});
```

I have tried using the readonly attribute, but this disables both the input and datetimepicker. Is there any way through which I can disable the input field but still allow the user to click on the calendar icon to pick a date?

[image: calendar screen shot]

Comment: What if i want to change the time 06:00 to w/c - (Text)?
i am using the datetimepicker also and textbox is not readonly because user want to change the only time to some text like w/c. 
In the textbox i can change the time to text but if exit out of that the values remains changing befault timepicker value

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `event.preventDefault()` on the keydown event on the input:

```
<input type="text" id="txtStart" class="form-control" onkeydown="event.preventDefault()">
```

Comment: Both onkeydown="return false" or onkeydown="event.preventDefault()" worked for me. Thank you. However, is it possible to open the calendar when the input field gets focused? Rather than clicking on the calendar icon?

Comment: @H.Khan hmm, it opens on focus when I try it on the jquery demo page.. Is your setup different? By focus you mean when you focus it via the tab key?

Comment: It doesn't open on focus when I try it. I am using MVC5 and fairly new to it.

Comment: did you try `onfocus="this.click()"` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried adding onfocus="this.click()" to the input field but still no luck :(

Comment: [I am using this datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Comment: @H.Khan oh, well, in this case you have to use `onfocus="$(this).next().trigger('click')"`

Comment: You're welcome, Khan. :) Next time, make sure to state the exact version/library used to ensure better and faster support.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will make sure I provide all the necessary information before asking a question.

Comment: @ManuelOtto you solution may work, but I fear that it will be not valid for all cases e.g. if I want to place the calendar icon on the right side of the input. See my answer, I suggest to use the [`ignoreReadonly`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#ignorereadonly) option of the component.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`ignoreReadonly`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#ignorereadonly) option that:

> Allow date picker show event to fire even when the associated input element has the `readonly="readonly"` property.

Here a working sample:

```js
$('#dtp1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A',
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
    ignoreReadonly: true
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Start</label>
    <div class="input-group date" id="dtp1">
        <input type="text" id="txtStart" class="form-control" readonly="readonly"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both readonly="readonly" & disabled="disabled" didn't worked for me.
Below line worked;

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="return false"/>
```