# <input> with readonly Attribute wont open widget

Tags: javascript, html, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am trying to use the https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker
and trying to make the input field read-only then even the date picker button getting disabled and I am not able to open the date picker widget

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control readonly" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way I can make the field read-only  and still access the date pciker widget?

Comment: Why would you set it to readonly if you want the user to be able to pick a value? That makes very little sense.

Comment: I want to make the user available button to select the date using datepicker and not to manually edit the input field after date has been selected in the input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restrict user to input data using datetimepicker and disable manual user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375097/how-to-restrict-user-to-input-data-using-datetimepicker-and-disable-manual-user)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem which I was facing.

Setting `ignoreReadonly:true` in the options for datetimepicker did the trick (**ignoreReadonly** **defaults to** **false**)

Input field was set to read-only using the read-only attribute in the HTML tag and the date-picker button was enabled using the above option.

Thanks.