# Disable input field with datetimepicker and only use the calendar icon as input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetime, datetimepicker

I looked, but none of the questions managed to answer my doubt, so I decided to do this topic.

That is my front end HTML:

```html
<div class="col">
    <label>Star Date *</label>
    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
        <input type="text" id="datetimepicker1Input" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" disabled>
        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And that is my JavaScript

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    //locale: 'pt-BR',
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
    maxDate: dateTomorrowBlock,
});
```

I tried to disable the field, but while doing this, it is also disabling the calendar field and I can not enter any value.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to demo this issue?

Comment: You can use `readonly` instead of `disabled` and add [`ignoreReadonly`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#ignorereadonly) option, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46414917/4131048) a live sample.

Comment: @VincenzoC worked perfectly, thx!